# Hive group by with cube and group by in the same query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, hiveql

say I'm observing speeding incidents where the table schema is the following:

```
create table speeding_data(
    date_of_occurrence date,
    year int,
    make string,
    model string,
    speed int
);
```

I'd like to observe average speeds under the different combinations of these characteristics but would like to have it always be grouped by the `date_of_occurrence`, e.g. something maybe like this

```
select date_of_occurrence, year, make, model, avg(speed) 
from speeding_data
group by date_of_occurrence
group by year, make, model with cube;
```

Just wondering if there was a way of producing this result in hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm gonna answer my own question, the idea is to go for the `GROUPING SET` clause, where I can go ahead and do:

```
select a, b, c, d, avg(e)
from tbl
group by a, b, c, d
grouping set ( (a), (a,b), (a,c), (a,d)...);
```